# FFMPEG: 4-channel audio workflow suggestions?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I’ve got a bunch of stereo files recorded for a documentary with a Zoom in 4 channel mode. Basically it’s sets of pairs of stereo file s— file A would be a stereo file with a lav or boom mike recording, file B of identical length would be a proper stereo recorded by Zoom itself.

Now I’m trying to convert all this into something I can correctly ingest into editing suite. Files A are a mess but I came up with a ffmpeg script which downconvert them to mono then reconvert them back to stereo (to get rid of inconsistensies). Now how do I merge two stereo files into a single WAV or AIFF file containing two separate stereo channels? I browsed around for any workflows and/or standards on that but can’t really find anything useful.

Any ideas on how to do that with ffmpeg (or anything else, really) would be appreciated!

Comment: Which editing app?

Comment: You can certainly use SoX to merge two stereo files together to get a single four-channel file like thus: `sox -M file1.wav file2.wav multi.wav`, but I fail to see why you wouldn't just import the two stereo files into your DAW directly?

Comment: @Mulvya Final Cut Pro X

Comment: @AkselA oh, Sox! Thanks! They are hard to sync to in-camera audio (corresponding to video files) separately, and the editing suite won't recognise them as pairs. So yeah, by merging them together I at least won't lose sync.

Comment: @Anton I see. I'm not too familiar with movie editing, but I'd expect there to be some mechanism in place for this, after all surround sound is a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if FCP-X reads multi track WAVs but you can output to a multi-track MOV.

```
ffmpeg -i file1.wav -i file2.wav -c copy -map 0 -map 1 file.mov
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but syncing two mov containers is not as easy as syncing mov to audio. Is there a way to get ffmpeg to output two stereo streams inside WAV or AIFF?

Comment: FFmpeg does not support multiple tracks in WAVE. Can you work with a 4-channel WAVE with two channels designated as Front Left/Right and the other two as Side or Back L/R?